# Can't open webpage using Firefox WebDriver using Selenium

Tags: selenium, webdriver, browser-automation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I face a problem while opening Firefox with Selenium script](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2213/i-face-a-problem-while-opening-firefox-with-selenium-script)

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class ok {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver test = new FirefoxDriver();
        test.get("www.google.com");
    }

}
```

When I run above script my Firefox is open with following message and I can't load google.com website:

> Would you like to help improve Mozilla Firefox by automatically reporting memory usage, performance, and responsiveness to Mozilla? All you need to do is to click on Yes or No button and then it won’t ever interrupt you!

I keep clicking Yes/No and it keeps showing the popup every time a new window opens, which stops any of my automated (Selenium) web application tests from working!

Comment: What version of selenium are you using here?

Comment: Which version of Firefox are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I Googled for 'disable "Would you like to help improve Mozilla Firefox by automatically reporting memory usage, performance, and responsiveness to Mozilla?"' and found [this](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=2328545).