# I face a problem while opening Firefox with Selenium script

Tags: selenium, webdriver, browser-automation

I face a problem while running Selenium scripts. I try to open Firefox using the following command:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("www.google.com");
    driver.quit();
}
```

But Firefox opens with Yes/No dialog with the following message:

> Would you like to help improve Mozilla Firefox by automatically
>   reporting memory usage, performance, and responsiveness to Mozilla?

I get this message every time. Selecting Yes or No has no effect. I can't understand whats the problem. Is it a problem with Firefox profile or WebDriver?

Comment: See also http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2201/cant-open-webpage-using-firefox-webdriver-using-selenium

Comment: Good spot @user246 - they're almost exact duplicates. Perhaps worth merging the two?

Comment: Maybe you could disable the pop-up in the Firefox browser settings 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
String baseURL ="http://www.google.com/";
driver.get(baseURL);
```

baseURL should be `http://www.google.com/` not `www.google.com`

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate on what advantage this will provide.

Comment: I think anusha is implying that the problem you are seeing is a result of not including the protocol in the URL.  I agree that this is possible.  What did you discover?

Answer (score 2):

What version of Firefox are you using?  Are you sure that the version of `WebDriver` you have supports the version of Firefox?  Try updating to the latest version of `WebDriver` and a version of Firefox that you know is supported like 7.0.1.
Another possible solution is that you can start Firefox with any profile instead of the default one that ships with Selenium.

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabailities();
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile("path_of_profile");
cap.SetCapability("firefox_profile", profile.ToBase64String());
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(cap);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial workaround in Ruby, which may lead you to the code you need; see http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3154

-Robin

Comment: Welcome to SQA.SE - your answer would be more complete if you gave a précis of the workaround here

Comment: Ah, sorry; the short version is "run firefox with a profile specified".  OTOH, I think this bug has been fixed in the 11 intervening moths. :)

Comment: Fair point - I didn't look at the date when it came up on the Review list :)

Answer (score 0):

Me suggest will be use custom Firefox profile. See how to create one on [this web page](http://girliemangalo.wordpress.com/2009/02/05/creating-firefox-profile-for-your-selenium-rc-tests/).